# How to connect Dart Aqueduct API with Google Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, aqueduct

I want to connect Aqueduct API with Google Firestore and perform Post/Get operations via API to Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an integration created that you can set to use Aqueduct API with Firestore directly. You can integrate App Engine with Dart - as you can check on this official repository [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine) - so you can use Dart language within Google Cloud Platform.

After that, you can integrate your App Engine with Firebase - as explained on [this article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration) - and this way, continue to use Dart - with the Aqueduct framework - in the development of your application.

Besides that, in case you think that would be useful to be added to GCP, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request, within [Google's System](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) for new features.

Let me know if the information helped you!